# Symfony 4 annotation routing does not work

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations, symfony4

I just started learning Symfony. I am following [this official tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html) exactly. Routing works fine when done with `config/routes.yaml`, but on using [annotations](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html#annotation-routes):

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Annotation\Route;

class LuckyController
{

    /**
     *  @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function number(){

        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body><h1>MyLucky Number: ' . $number . '</h1></body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
    Exception thrown when handling an exception
(Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: [Semantical Error]
 The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Annotation\Route" in method
App\Controller\LuckyController::number() does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded
 in C:\wamp\vhosts\mysymfony4\config/routes\../../src/Controller/ (which is
 being imported from "C:\wamp\vhosts\mysymfony4\config/routes/annotations.yaml"). Make sure
 annotations are installed and enabled.)
```

Comment: have you installed `sensio/framework-extra-bundle`?

Comment: @Federkun sensio/framework-extra-bundle is installed, according to my composer.json. Is there any action I'm supposed to take with it that's missing form the tutorial?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found out my mistake. I used the wrong namespace for routing.

`use Symfony\Component\Annotation\Route;`

It should have been:

`use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem with my first Symfony 4 project on a standard Apache web server.

Creating a [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) file in my public folder fixed the issue.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I added file in public/ catalog and my application run in prod  server ;))

Comment: Before you check anything else, try this solution! Best suggestion for a new Symfony 4 project, especially when you use "php bin/console make:controller" to create your first controller.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, adding 'symfony/apache-pack' solved the problem:

```
"composer require symfony/apache-pack"
```

You need this if you run Symfony in a browser via */public/*.

Comment: Is "`apache bundle`" the literal name? Or do you mean the "`apache` bundle" or the "Apache bundle"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen its not a bundle in technical way ... it's just a "pack" https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#symfony-packs ,  I edited original post.

Answer (score 6):

I want to give additional advice about annotation errors in Symfony 4:

I handled my issue with that:

My project doesn't have file *config/routes/annotation.yaml*, so create that file and write these lines:

```
// config/routes/annotations.yaml

controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

Comment: Had the same issue, and adding this file worked for me. I'm not sure why the Flex recipe didn't create this file automatically!

Comment: Installing `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` creates `config/routes/annotation.yaml`.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you install the `annotations` library with `composer require annotations`.

This was my issue and not other ones described here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've imported the required classes to your controller.

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
```

Comment: Your answers works. Any ideas why the official tutorial use `Symfony\Component\Annotation\Route` instead of `Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route`?

Comment: Because the FrameworkExtraBundle is no longer used in S4.  I was puzzled you accepted this.  A ["composer require annotation"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html#annotation-routes) was all you really needed.

Comment: @Cerad I did `composer require annotation` as instructed by the tutorial. It didn't work

Comment: Hmmm.  Seems unlikely.  I just did a quick install and it works as expected.  You really should not have to import the framework extra bundle classes.  Just the symfony route like the original question shows.  Might want to start a fresh project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (in my Symfony 5 project), but my mistake was using single quote instead of double quotes for the route and route name. Sometimes small silly mistakes will waste a lot of your time. By the way, in Symfony 4/Symfony 5 we should avoid using Routing of FrameworkExtraBundle.

```
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route
```

We should use symfony component (Routing/Annotation).

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a similar error, he/she can check if he/she wrote "route" correctly. I forgot the closing brace.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30112075)

Answer (score -2):

For Symfony 4 with the file [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) in the public folder, solve the issue with the Routing Annotation.

Comment: Is "public" literal?

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*).